DNS server not being used for resolution on an AWS VPC network
I have a VPC in AWS with multiple public and private subnets in different availability zones.
I want to host my own DNS on this network to use single label hostnames. For example, I want to use mydatabase instead of  mydatabase.company.com.
I deployed a VM in one  subnet, and installed and configured dnsmasq with a CNAME to translate the hostnames.
I validated on the DNS server returned the expected response to dig mydatabase. I also validated the networking  and dnsmasq running on the right port because the expected response is received on another client machine on the network for dig mydatabase @172.31.1.36 where 172.31.1.36 is the IP address of my DNS server.
I set the the DHCP Option Set on the VPC to one with options of domain-name-servers: 172.31.1.36, expecting that machines on this network will be sent to my DNS server instead of the Amazon provided DNS.  resolvectl status on these machines (in either a public or private subnet) returns:
ubuntu@ip-172-31-1-58:~$ resolvectl status
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enX0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 172.31.1.36
       DNS Servers: 172.31.1.36

However, dig mydatabase on these client machines returns no response. Logs on the DNS server record activity when, on a different machine, I run dig mydatabase@172.31.1.36 but doesn't record anything when I run dig mydatabase. The same is true for dig google.com@172.31.1.36 and dig google.com. Clearly, the client machines aren't using my DNS server for resolution.
I was expecting that when I updated the DHCP Option Set on the VPC that the network router would then forward all DNS queries on the network to my DNS server.
What have I missed?
Is there any way I can see which DNS server is answering my client machines when they query google.com? (as  I've observed that mine is not)
What is the difference between the Global and Link 2 sections reported by resolvectl status?
Are my client machines preferring Global over Link 2 for some reason?
I have seen that there might be the option to set the DNS server on each client machine, involving installing resolvconf. I'd rather not do that, as I would need to do it on all machines deployed into the network. I would rather handle this at the network level.
My VPC has the Enable DNS resolution option set (as per AWS defaults). I tried disabling this without success.

Is there any way I can see which DNS server is answering my client this is platform specific, but a packet capture on the endpoint is usually informative. Also note that some platforms have multiple ways to resolve names such as LLMNR and mDNS.

The resolution of short names (as opposed to FQDNs) is a client side setting, known as search domains. You need to configure each of your instances to have your domain in its search domains. This can be done via DHCP option 119. In dnsmasq, such a configuration would look like this:
dhcp-option=option:domain-search,company.com,subdomain.company.com

Additionally, as this is in AWS, please make sure your custom DNS server forwards to the AWS default DNS servers, as a lot of special AWS functionality depends on being able to resolve to them.
